# Undeclared identifier error on using square() function given in a book

Tags: c++

I came across the square() function in a book on C++.
On implementing the function as given in the book Xcode gives an 'undeclared identifier' error. I have tried including 'cmath' and 'math.h' header files but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. I cannot find a header file for it and I am not even sure if that's the actual problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int x=0; x<10; ++x)
    {
        cout<< x << '\t' << square(x) << endl;
    }
}
```

EDIT: The book is called principles of C++ by Bjarne (the creator of C++)
And this guy wrote a whole chapter on Statements explaining it with several examples containing the undefined function square(). After 10 or so examples the next chapter starts with- "In the program above, what was square(i)?"

[The code that confused me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZbOD.png)

[Next chapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rkRp.png)

Comment: There is no such standard function.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

Comment: Perhaps the book also has the implementation of it, which you overlooked?

Comment: It could also be one of the book's exercises, which you forgot about. Which book is it?

Comment: `auto square (auto x) { return x * x; }`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Apparently, the author wanted to confuse the reader intentionally. I have edited the question with images from the book. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `square()` function in the c++ standard library, you need to implement it.

Anyway, there is the function `pow(number, power)`, it calculates the power of a number, you can use it including the `cmath` header.

Comment: Note that `std::pow()` always returns a floating point number even if arguments are integrals.

Comment: @Evg Recently, I found out to my personal surprise that `x * x` results in the exact same code like `std::pow(x, 2)`: [Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/raE6zco1v). ;-) (...for `double x` admittedly.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat [Indeed](https://godbolt.org/z/3o34oKbjc). Very interesting observation. But for `3` they both call `pow`.